# Can I avoid spaghettification with a spin?

Tags: black-holes, rotational-dynamics, universe, rotation, space

I am aware of spaghettification effect caused by entering a black hole, as well as fundamental physics of an object in space, so here is my theoretical construct:

- if I place an object in space where there aren't active (great enough to cause interference) gravitational forces and give a spin to this object, the object shall spin with constant speed indefinitely (let's do not account for solar wind friction)

based on this logic a question arises:

**is it possible to calculate (or possible in general) what speed of spin is required to nullify the spaghettification effect?**

(an analogy: if I wrap my wife in a carpet and roll the carpet in a way that she will roll out from the carpet with a spin and towards a black hole, would be that spin always negated by approaching the black hole or is there a possibility that spin could overcome a spaghettification and not kill her)

[image]

*extra points if you can provide (grown-up-)child-like / non-academic explanation

Comment: No speed of spin will cancel out the spaghettification effect because, although the magnitude of centripedal force can be controlled it does not act in the opposite direction to gravity.

Comment: "*I wrap my wife in a carpet and roll the carpet in a way that she will roll out from the carpet with a spin and towards a black hole*"... Trouble in paradise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spaghettification cannot be avoided by spin.

The differential tidal forces that cause spaghettification act in two ways. There is a force that stretches a body along the radial direction towards the black hole, but there is also a (often forgotten) compressive force that acts in the perpendicular tangential direction. These two forces have roughly the same magnitude and increase rapidly (as $r^{-3}$) with decreasing distance to the black hole centre.

Giving an object a spin would reduce the effects of the compressive force if the spin-axis is perpendicular to radial diection, but will exacerbate the effects of the stretching force. Alternatively you could point the spin-axis at the black hole. This would have no effect on the radial stretching, but would at least oppose  the compressive forces. Either way spaghettification is the result, since as I said above, both forces continue to grow rapidly as the distance from the black hole decreases, whereas the centrifugal force defined by the initial spin will be at best constant and may actually *decrease* (see below).

A further point of complexity to consider is that the deformation induced (on an initially spherical body) by the initialisation of the spaghettification process will result in a tidal torque on any spinning object, if the spin-axis is perpendicular to the radial direction. If the object (a person?) is non-spherical to begin with, then this torque will be present immediately. The gravitational force (just thinking in Newtonian terms) will be stronger for the side of any elongated object closer to the black hole. As a result,  if such an elongated object rotates about an axis perpendicular to the radial direction, then a torque will act to slow down the rotation until the "long axis" of any such object is stabilised in the radial direction. If the spin axis is in the radial direction then this complexity does not arise.

Comment: now I got confused so let me sum it if I understand it...  **1)** spaghettification cant be nullified with a spin **2)** black hole will stop any spin and initiate spaghettification **3)** speed of spin needs to be higher then speed of light to overcome spaghettification? (my assumption - not sure if it's valid) **4)** when spaghettification will kick in the spinning object will stop spinning at the front and will break at point closest to the black hole and roll out like a carpet into the black hole. correct?